# change pictures every 2 sec

Tags: java, swing, timer, imageicon

I stack a bit so if anyone has any ideas it would be helpful.
So currently the program is compiling and running but I do not know how to finish it.
I am using eclipse. What i want to do is when i start the program to change 4 different pictures in every 2 seconds so if you have any advices do not be shy. Here is the program.

```
/** Here is the GUI of the program
 * class name SlideShowGui.java
 * @author Kiril Anastasov
 * @date 07/03/2012
 */

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SlideShowGui extends JPanel implements ActionListener 
{
    JLabel name, comments, images;
    JTextField namejtf, commentsjtf, captionjtf;
    JButton submit;
    ImageIcon pictures, pictures2, pictures3, pictures4;
    boolean go = true;

    SlideShowGui()
    {
        name = new JLabel("Name:");
        this.add(name);

        namejtf = new JTextField(15);
        this.add(namejtf);

        comments = new JLabel("Comments:");
        this.add(comments);

        commentsjtf = new JTextField(15);
        this.add(commentsjtf);

        submit = new JButton("Submit");
        this.add(submit);
        submit.addActionListener(this);
        pictures = new ImageIcon("galileo1.jpg");
        images = new JLabel(pictures);

        pictures2 = new ImageIcon("galileo2.jpg");
        pictures3 = new ImageIcon("galileo3.jpg");
        pictures4 = new ImageIcon("galileo4.jpg");
        this.add(images);

        captionjtf = new JTextField(24);
        this.add(captionjtf);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {

    }
}
```

---

```
/**The driver class of the program. Here is the JFrame 
 * class name TestSlideShow.java
 * @author Kiril Anastasov
 * @date 07/03/2012
 */

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class TestSlideShow 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        JFrame application = new JFrame();
        SlideShowGui panel = new SlideShowGui();
        application.add(panel);
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        application.setSize(300,600);
        application.setLocation(400,100);
        application.setVisible(true);


    }

}
```

Comment: A short concise question and actually explaining where exactly the problem is usually helps in getting an answer. "Help me finish program" and a wall of code makes you look lazy and doesn't invite people to answer.

Comment: Well, I am trying to change a picture in every 2 seconds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- put `Icon / ImageIcons` to the `Queue`, `Map`, `Array`, `List`, `Vector`
- by starting [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) pick up `Icon / ImageIcon` from the array
- add [Icon / ImageIcons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) to the [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html), by using [JLabel#setIcon()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29)
- code related for Swing GUI should be initialized from `invokeLater()`, more in the [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)