# difficulty with actionPerformed method

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, jbutton, actionlistener

Hi guys when the submit button is clicked i start to increment and when it is 2 i want it change the picture when i is 4 i want to change to another pic but it doesn't do it so if anyone have an idea it would be great. I am using eclipse and the program is compiling and running. Here is the code

```
/** Here is the GUI of the program
 * class name SlideShowGui.java
 * @author Kiril Anastasov
 * @date 07/03/2012
 */

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;   

public class SlideShowGui extends JPanel  implements ActionListener, Runnable
{
    JLabel name, comments, images;
    JTextField namejtf, commentsjtf, captionjtf;
    JButton submit;
    ImageIcon pictures;


    SlideShowGui()
    {


        name = new JLabel("Name:");
        this.add(name);

        namejtf = new JTextField(15);
        this.add(namejtf);

        comments = new JLabel("Comments:");
        this.add(comments);

        commentsjtf = new JTextField(15);
        this.add(commentsjtf);

        submit = new JButton("Submit");
        this.add(submit);
        submit.addActionListener(this);


        pictures = new ImageIcon("galileo1.jpg");
        images = new JLabel(pictures);
        this.add(images);


        pictures = new ImageIcon("galileo2.jpg");
        this.add(images);



        captionjtf = new JTextField(24);
        this.add(captionjtf);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();

        if(ae.getSource() == submit)
        {

            int i = 0;
            boolean go = true;
            while(go)
            {

                i++;
                System.out.println(i);

                try 
                { 
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    if(i == 2)
                    {
                        pictures = new ImageIcon("galileo2.jpg");
                        images.setIcon(pictures);   
                    }


                } 
                catch (InterruptedException ie) 
                {
                     System.out.println("thread exception");
                }
//              pictures = new ImageIcon("galileo2.jpg");
//              images.setIcon(pictures);




            System.out.println("test");
        }


    }



}

    public void run() 
    {

    }
}

/**The driver class of the program. Here is the JFrame 
 * class name TestSlideShow.java
 * @author Kiril Anastasov
 * @date 07/03/2012
 */

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class TestSlideShow 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        JFrame application = new JFrame();
        SlideShowGui panel = new SlideShowGui();
        application.add(panel);
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        application.setSize(300,600);
        application.setLocation(400,100);
        application.setVisible(true);


    }

}
```

Comment: maybe I was bind, but what's `pictures = new ImageIcon("galileo2.jpg");`, heavens where is placed this file???, in Java package???, somewhere on HDD??? or ???, because your Icon / ImageIcon pretty could be null :-)

Answer (score 8):

never, really never use `Thread.sleep()` in Swing, nor initialized from Swing `Listener`, this code line cause freeze or stop for repainting in the `JComponent`, use `Swing Timer`, rest is in my [answer to your previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9606293/714968), clean_up this code

EDIT ---> [here is four ways how to do it for Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7049095/714968)

Comment: @Binyamin Sharet I glad to see you here :-)